# Attempting to place auction items into an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, types, casting

I am trying to place some auction items into an array list, each item has a different type akin to what kind of item it is.

Books are classified as books, Collectables are collectables, etc.

Since an array list can only hold several of one type of item, how can I place these different types of items into the same array list?

Comment: `ArrayList` can hold `Object`s - so, lots of different things simultaneously.  Obviously this isn't always desirable, but it's achivable

Comment: Depending on your needs and control of the model you could add a supertype that Books and Collectables both share and use that for your list.

Comment: Use the type system to create types that are useful to you. It seems extremely unlikely that making a type for every kind of thing that can be auctioned is going to do anything but make things complicated.

Comment: I’d categorise your items, then you’d have a List of AuctionItem’s, each with a category and associate data

Comment: The duplink gives the general solution.  In your case, I would try to come up with a  superclass or interface that is common to all of the objects in the list and use that ... rather than `java.lang.Object`.  But `Object` *will work* ... if there is nothing in common to the elements.